# How to pass more than one filters in where condition on a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a mysql like below

```
SELECT p.EANHotelID
FROM propertyattributelink AS p
WHERE (p.attributeId = 40
       OR p.attributeId =41
       OR p.attributeId = 45
       OR p.attributeId =52)
  AND (p.attributeId =130
       OR p.attributeId =133
       OR p.attributeId =135)
  AND (p.attributeId=385
       OR p.attributeId=399);
```

Need to add multiple AND and OR conditions.
Can you please help me on this..

Comment: What is the problem with the code you already have?

Comment: attributeid cannot simultaneously be both x and y.

Comment: i cant understand your code. attributeId cant have 2 values 40 AND 130

Comment: Second line of your query where you are using `as p` is incorrect. It should be replaced with just `p`. Other than this, what error are u getting. What do you mean by adding multiple `and` and `or` condition?

Comment: @Utsav Syamala's use of aliases is fine.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Utsav: MySQL does accept optional `AS` keyword before the table alias, just like SQL Server does. (This is inconsistent with ANSI SQL standard.) Other databases like Oracle do not accept the `AS` keyword in this context. I agree that best practice is to *omit* the optional and non-standard `AS` keyword preceding table and view aliases.

Comment: @Strawberry - Ok just verified in rextester. You are right. It doesnt work this way in Oracle, so I assumed it is ansi standard.

Comment: @spencer7593 - Yes. Thanks for the info. I just verified that mysql does support it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are no rows that will satisfy the query in the question, perhaps you were meaning to use `OR` in place of `AND`?

We could string together a whole bunch of `OR` conditions. Or, we could make use of the `IN` comparison operator:

```
 SELECT p.EANHotelID
   FROM propertyattributelink p
  WHERE p.attributeId IN (40,41,45,52,130,133,135,385,399)
```

As far as the "Need to add multiple AND and OR conditions", we can do that.

Here's some AND and OR conditions added.

```
 SELECT p.EANHotelID
   FROM propertyattributelink p
  WHERE p.attributeId IN (40,41,45,52,130,133,135,385,399)

    AND ( 1=1 OR ( 'cat'<'dog' AND p.attributeid IS NOT NULL ) )
```

While this satisfies the specification "add multiple AND and OR conditions", I suspect this does not satisfy the *actual* requirement.

---

Likely, the actual requirement is to identify values of `EANHotelID` for which some *set* of rows exists.

If I wanted to return values of `EANHotelID` where there was at least one row that satisfies each set of criteria, I could do something like this:

```
 SELECT p.EANHotelID
   FROM propertyattributelink p
  GROUP BY p.EANHotelID
 HAVING MAX( p.attributeid IN (40,41,45,52) )
    AND MAX( p.attributeid IN (130,133,135) )
    AND MAX( p.attributeid IN (385,399) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your logic is in the where statement will always result in 0 return rows, as p.attributeId can't be more than one value as others have said in the comments.
Just speculating, you may be wanting three different types in which you want to include all the attributeId's listed distinguished by type. See below:

```
SELECT p.EANHotelID
,case when p.attributeId in (40,41,45,52) then 1
 when p.attributeId in (130,133,135) then 2
 when p.attributeId in (385,399) then 3
 else 9
 end Type_
FROM propertyattributelink  p
WHERE Type_ <> 9  --filters out the attributeId's not listed
```

---

To add a new answer after gaining insight into the table structure:
Since the eanHotelID has multiple rows, one for each attributeID it has, use the reflexive inner join (self inner join) multiple times.  The "inner join" is your "AND"'s, the "in (40,41,45,52)" is your "OR"'s.

```
SELECT a.EANHotelID, a.attributeId a1, b.attributeId a2, c.attributeId a3
FROM
(
SELECT EANHotelID, attributeId
FROM propertyattributelink
WHERE attributeId in (40,41,45,52)
)  a

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT EANHotelID, attributeId
FROM propertyattributelink
WHERE attributeId in (130,133,135)
)  b ON (a.EANHotelID=b.EANHotelID)

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT EANHotelID, attributeId
FROM propertyattributelink
WHERE attributeId in (385,399)
)  c ON (a.EANHotelID=c.EANHotelID)
```

What you are left with is only the eanHotelID's and their attributes which match the criteria. There are probably better, more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this degree of speculation is beneficial to anyone.

Comment: Thanks all. Here the attributes refer hotel amenities like free wifi,free break fast etc..


2001-Free breakfast
3547-Breakfast service
2405-Free internet access

2407-Free dial-up Internet access
2392-Free wired high-speed Internet

Now the the query should return eanHotelIds (wifi AND freebreakfast)..

WHERE (p.attributeId = 2001
       OR p.attributeId =3547
       OR p.attributeId = 2405)
  AND (p.attributeId =2407
       OR p.attributeId =2392)

Comment: @Syamala  Is the table structure such that for a specific hotel (eanHotelIds), there are multiple rows with different attributeIds?
Such as:

eanHotelIds : attributeId
001 : 2001
001 : 2392
002 : 3547
002 : 2407
ect..

Comment: @Syamala See my revised answer above.